# What is needed to execute visual studio 2005 web tests?

Tags: mstest, web-testing

Our test department has a series of web tests created using Visual Studio 2005 Team Tester Edition.

I would like to be able to execute these tests against my local machine. I attempted to use the mstest command line tool to accomplish this as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487(VS.80).aspx). But I get the following error:

> C:\WebTests\Participant>mstest
>   /testcontainer:AE_ActivityDue_Touch.webtest
>   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command
>   Line Tool Version 9.0.30729.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Loading
>   AE_ActivityDue_Touch.webtest...
>   AE_ActivityDue_Touch.webtest File
>   extension specified '.webtest' is not
>   a valid test extension.

Any hints on how I can get this to work? Eventually we want to work them into our CI process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need VSTS Test Edition. No bueno.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/test/default.aspx

Comment: BTW I know that is for 2008 but it's the same for 2005.

Comment: that is a really poor deign choice. So if I want to work these tests into my CI process, I have to install VSTS on my build machine? Crazy talk!